Linux Smart Card Local User Authentication (multiple p11_child card phases)
I have a widely distributed smart card (I have zero control over) for authentication, which I am trying to use to authenticate a normal local user.  No LDAP/AD/Kerberos/etc, not even a certificate authority--just a single smart card authenticating a single account.  With some struggles, I apparently got the system to recognize the smart card as belonging to the user, and it even asks for the PIN to authenticate the card.  Investigation shows some kind of weird-flip flop state where p11_child returns two sets of information. However, the user is not authenticated since it grabs the label in one phase and tries to apply the label in a different phase.  /usr/libexec/sssd/p11_child --dumpable=1 --debug-microseconds=0 --debug-timestamps=1 --logger=stderr --backtrace=1 --debug-level=0x2f7f0 --pre --verify partial_chain,no_ocsp --ca_db /etc/sssd/pki/sssd_auth_ca_db.pem --chain-id 1 |& grep "found cert" will return either of:
Output set A
(2024-12-30 18:00:31): [p11_child[179092]] [read_certs] (0x4000): [CID#1] found cert[Certificate for PIV Authentication][/C=UK/O=FAKE/OU=MoD/OU=PKI/CN=KUREGI.JEFFREY.M.65312238]
(2024-12-30 18:00:31): [p11_child[179092]] [read_certs] (0x4000): [CID#1] found cert[Certificate for Digital Signature][/C=UK/O=FAKE/OU=MoD/OU=PKI/CN=KUREGI.JEFFREY.M.65312238]
(2024-12-30 18:00:31): [p11_child[179092]] [read_certs] (0x4000): [CID#1] found cert[Certificate for Key Management][/C=UK/O=FAKE/OU=MoD/OU=PKI/CN=KUREGI.JEFFREY.M.65312238]
(2024-12-30 18:00:31): [p11_child[179092]] [read_certs] (0x4000): [CID#1] found cert[Certificate for Card Authentication][/C=UK/O=FAKE/OU=MoD/OU=PKI/serialNumber=5AAAE936-08C9-4CEF-8AE0-996BF87F08ED]

Output set B:
(2024-12-30 18:00:28): [p11_child[179077]] [read_certs] (0x4000): [CID#1] found cert[CAC Email Signature Certificate][/C=UK/O=FAKE/OU=MoD/OU=PKI/CN=KUREGI.JEFFREY.M.65312238]
(2024-12-30 18:00:28): [p11_child[179077]] [read_certs] (0x4000): [CID#1] found cert[CAC Email Encryption Certificate][/C=UK/O=FAKE/OU=MoD/OU=PKI/CN=KUREGI.JEFFREY.M.65312238]
(2024-12-30 18:00:28): [p11_child[179077]] [read_certs] (0x4000): [CID#1] found cert[CAC Cert 4][/C=UK/O=FAKE/OU=MoD/OU=PKI/serialNumber=5AAAE936-08C9-4CEF-8AE0-996BF87F08ED]
(2024-12-30 18:00:28): [p11_child[179077]] [read_certs] (0x4000): [CID#1] found cert[CAC Cert 5][/C=UK/O=FAKE/OU=MoD/OU=PKI/CN=KUREGI.JEFFREY.M.65312238]

However, both "CAC Cert 5" and "Certificate for PIV Authentication" appear to contain the same certificate.  But, the problem is that if the system grabs "CAC Cert 5" during PREAUTH, it cannot it during AUTHENTICATE since it has flip/flopped to the other side.  In other words, I can either one of the following two commands and they will work 50% of the time.  Only if I interleave the two commands (in the correct phase) will I get continual success.  (You may not believe how long it took me to understand what was going on as things sometimes worked and sometimes didn't during debugging!) Presumably if the p11_client AUTHENTICATE call ran twice and took whichever one worked, life would be good.  Is there a better way other than modifying the source code?
Phase A command: "/usr/libexec/sssd/p11_child" "--dumpable=1" "--debug-microseconds=0" "--debug-timestamps=1" "--logger=stderr" "--backtrace=1" "--debug-level=0x2f7f0" "--pin" "--auth" "--label" "Certificate for PIV Authentication" "--key_id" "01" "--token_name" "KUREGI.JEFFREY.M.65312238" "--module_name" "/usr/lib64/pkcs11/opensc-pkcs11.so" "--verify" "partial_chain,no_ocsp" "--ca_db" "/etc/sssd/pki/sssd_auth_ca_db.pem" "--chain-id" "1" 
Phase B command: /usr/libexec/sssd/p11_child --dumpable=1 --debug-microseconds=0 --debug-timestamps=1 --logger=stderr --backtrace=1 --debug-level=0x2f7f0 --pin --auth --label CAC Cert 5 --key_id 0005 --token_name KUREGI.JEFFREY.M.65312238 --module_name /usr/lib64/pkcs11/opensc-pkcs11.so --verify partial_chain,no_ocsp --ca_db /etc/sssd/pki/sssd_auth_ca_db.pem --chain-id 1
The pam configuration is auth sufficient pam_sss.so allow_missing_name try_cert_auth
The sssd configuration is:
[sssd]
services = pam
enable_files_domain = True
domains = thetest.uk
default_domain_suffix = thetest.uk
certificate_verification = partial_chain,no_ocsp

[domain/thetest.uk]
id_provider = proxy
proxy_lib_name = files
auth_provider = none
local_auth_policy = only

[certmap/thetest.uk/jeff]
matchrule = <SUBJECT>CN=KUREGI\.JEFFREY\.M\.65312238,OU=PKI,OU=MoD,O=DSTL,C=UK

[pam]
pam_cert_auth = True

Oh, and random tip for random people having problems in the future, the matchrule entry for SUBJECT for my system was in the reversed order (LDAP order I guess) compared to what it was in the certificate.  sssctl cert-show <base64encodedstring> will show you what is actually used, where the base64 encoded string can be found in the sssd logs (search for Found cert)
